# Can't access array in the main method

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I'm trying to create a class that, in one method, creates the deck of cards, and in another method, **I would like it to shuffle the deck 1000 times and then print to the console.** *(This is a lab i was told to do by my teacher)*
my problem is that i created the arrays inside the **CardDeck** method, and i cannot access them outside of that method. I'm looking for an answer that is simple for a newbie at programming can understand, and apply into my current code.
 **This program is written in java.**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // mah lovely arrays ^.^
        CardDeck();

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int q = 0; q < 52; q++) {
            int rand = random.nextInt(52);
        }
    }

    public static void CardDeck() {

        final String[] deckSuit = new String[52];
        String[] deckKind = new String[52];
        int[] deckValue = new int[52];

        String spade = "Spades";
        String diamond = "Diamonds";
        String heart = "Hearts";
        String club = "Clubs";

        // set the respective suits
        for (int q = 0; q < 13; q++) {
            deckSuit[q] = spade;
        }
        for (int q = 13; q < 26; q++) {
            deckSuit[q] = diamond;
        }
        for (int q = 26; q < 39; q++) {
            deckSuit[q] = heart;
        }
        for (int q = 39; q < 52; q++) {
            deckSuit[q] = club;
        }
        // set the kind of card
        for (int q = 0; q < 52; q += 13) {
            deckKind[q] = "Two";
            deckKind[q + 1] = "Three";
            deckKind[q + 2] = "Four";
            deckKind[q + 3] = "Five";
            deckKind[q + 4] = "Six";
            deckKind[q + 5] = "Seven";
            deckKind[q + 6] = "Eight";
            deckKind[q + 7] = "Nine";
            deckKind[q + 8] = "Ten";
            deckKind[q + 9] = "Jack";
            deckKind[q + 10] = "Queen";
            deckKind[q + 11] = "King";
            deckKind[q + 12] = "Ace";
        }

        for (int q = 0; q < 52; q += 13) {
            deckValue[q] = 2;
            deckValue[q + 1] = 3;
            deckValue[q + 2] = 4;
            deckValue[q + 3] = 5;
            deckValue[q + 4] = 6;
            deckValue[q + 5] = 7;
            deckValue[q + 6] = 8;
            deckValue[q + 7] = 9;
            deckValue[q + 8] = 10;
            deckValue[q + 9] = 10;
            deckValue[q + 10] = 10;
            deckValue[q + 11] = 10;
            deckValue[q + 12] = 11;
        }


        //display all the cards
        for (int q = 0; q < 52; q++) {
            System.out.println("[" + deckSuit[q] + ", " + deckKind[q] + ", " + deckValue[q] + "]");
        }
    }
    //declare ye methods here
}
```

Comment: on addition to  below answer you should use camelCase  naming conventions for better understanding of code

Comment: code formatting is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of solution

1. make array static public
2. return the array from the function

Answer (score 0):

Because you created / declared the array's inside the CardDeck method, that' why you are not able to use outside of that method.

you can either declare array as instance variable and initialize in CardDeck() method.

Answer (score 0):

A first solution is to declare your variable at a higher scope. You can either create a static member in the Deck class that will be accessible by any static method (in this case `main()` and `CardDeck()`) or you can create a variable in the `main()` method and pass it as a parameter of a `CardDeck(String[])` method.

But I think a better solution would be to change the prototype of `CardDeck()` method to `String[] createDeck()`. The method first create the deck and then returns it. In the `main()` method, you then store the returned value in a local `String[]` that can be used in the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Your brackets are not formatted correctly.  You have an extra curly bracket above `public static void CardDeck().

Fixed code:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Deck {

    public static void main(String args []){
        // mah lovely arrays ^.^


        CardDeck();

        Random random = new Random();
        for(int q = 0;q<52;q++){
        int rand = random.nextInt(52);

        }
    }

    public static void CardDeck(){

           final String[] deckSuit = new String[52];
            String[] deckKind = new String[52];
               int[] deckValue = new int[52];

            String spade = "Spades";
            String diamond = "Diamonds";
            String heart = "Hearts";
            String club = "Clubs";



            // set the respective suits
            for(int q = 0;q<13;q++){
                deckSuit[q] = spade;
            }
            for(int q = 13;q<26;q++){
                deckSuit[q] = diamond;
            }
            for(int q = 26;q<39;q++){
                deckSuit[q] = heart;
            }
            for(int q = 39;q<52;q++){   
                deckSuit[q] = club;
            }
            // set the kind of card
            for(int q = 0;q<52;q+=13){
                deckKind[q] = "Two";
                deckKind[q+1] = "Three";
                deckKind[q+2] = "Four";
                deckKind[q+3] = "Five";
                deckKind[q+4] = "Six";
                deckKind[q+5] = "Seven";
                deckKind[q+6] = "Eight";
                deckKind[q+7] = "Nine";
                deckKind[q+8] = "Ten";
                deckKind[q+9] = "Jack";
                deckKind[q+10] = "Queen";
                deckKind[q+11] = "King";
                deckKind[q+12] = "Ace";
            }

            for(int q = 0;q<52;q+=13){
                deckValue[q] = 2;
                deckValue[q+1] = 3;
                deckValue[q+2] = 4;
                deckValue[q+3] = 5;
                deckValue[q+4] = 6;
                deckValue[q+5] = 7;
                deckValue[q+6] = 8;
                deckValue[q+7] = 9;
                deckValue[q+8] = 10;
                deckValue[q+9] = 10;
                deckValue[q+10] = 10;
                deckValue[q+11] = 10;
                deckValue[q+12] = 11;
            }


            //display all the cards
            for(int q = 0;q<52;q++){

                System.out.println("["+deckSuit[q]+", "+deckKind[q]+", "+deckValue[q]+"]");
                }   

        //declare ye methods here
        }

}
```